# Pivot table sorting

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, pivot

I have a pivot table result as below :

```
           len
           MERCHANT_NAME
MCC_CODE    
0.0        58635982
742.0      7378
763.0      750
780.0      281
1520.0     974


  frame_mcc_merchant_pvt=pd.pivot_table(frame_mcc_merchant,index=['MCC_CODE'],
                        values=['MERCHANT_NAME'],aggfunc=[len],fill_value=0)
```

I need to sort the pivot table by the values of the len of merchant name ?
Pls help

Answer (score 0):

Remove `[]` for avoid `MultiIndex` and then sorting by [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
frame_mcc_merchant_pvt=pd.pivot_table(frame_mcc_merchant,
                                      index='MCC_CODE',
                                      values='MERCHANT_NAME',
                                      aggfunc=len,
                                      fill_value=0).sort_values('MERCHANT_NAME')
```

Answer (score 0):

my code here is copying over the pivot table results, and then checking for the average (arithmetic mean value) and the standard deviation of a batch.

At the section where i copied over the numbers, i am sure you could sort them for size, by getting max / min and then loop through.

```
Private Sub EvaluateButton_Click()
    Dim EvaRange As Range               'Evaluation range
    Dim i As Integer                    'Counter for free columns
    Dim n As Integer                    'Counter for number of measurements
    Dim a As Integer                    'Counter for Abfragenummer
    Dim AbfrageZahl As Variant          'Frage nach der Abfrage
    Dim z As Integer                    'counter für Abfrage
    Worksheets("testsheet").Activate
    'MsgBox "The name of the active sheet is " & ActiveSheet.Name
    z = 0
    AbfrageZahl = InputBox("Bitte geben Sie eine Zahl >1 ein für die Abfrage. Q2 2022: 2, Q4 2022: 3, Q2 2023: 3 usw.")
    z = AbfrageZahl - 2
    Set EvaRange = Range("C10:C999")
    EvaRange.Copy Cells(15, 7 + 2 * z)
    Range(Cells(15, 7 + 2 * z), (Cells(Rows.Count, 7 + 2 * z))).Select
        i = 15
        For Each self In Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
            self.Copy Cells(i, 8 + 2 * z)
            i = i + 1
        Next
    Cells(i - 1, 8 + 2 * z).Clear        'und jetzt die Auswertung
    n = i - 16                           'definiere mein n
    Cells(1, 8 + 2 * z).Value = Date     'schreibe Abfragedatum
    Cells(2, 8 + 2 * z).Value = n        'schreibe mein n
    Cells(3, 8 + 2 * z).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Range(Cells(15, 8 + 2 * z), Cells(Rows.Count, 8 + 2 * z)))
    Cells(4, 8 + 2 * z).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev_S(Range(Cells(15, 8 + 2 * z), Cells(Rows.Count, 8 + 2 * z)))
    Cells(5, 8 + 2 * z).Value = Range("C1").Value
    Cells(6, 8 + 2 * z).Value = Range("C2").Value
    Cells(7, 8 + 2 * z).Value = Range("C3").Value
    Cells(8, 8 + 2 * z).Value = Range("C4").Value
    Cells(9, 8 + 2 * z).Value = Range("C5").Value
    Cells(10, 8 + 2 * z).Value = Range("C6").Value
    Cells(11, 8 + 2 * z).Value = Tabelle2.Name
    Cells(12, 8 + 2 * z).Value = AbfrageZahl
    Cells(1, 7 + 2 * z).Value = "Date of Review"
    Cells(2, 7 + 2 * z).Value = "n, Number of Measurements"
    Cells(3, 7 + 2 * z).Value = "µ, arithmetic mean"
    Cells(4, 7 + 2 * z).Value = "Sigma, stand. Dev. of a batch"
    Cells(5, 7 + 2 * z).Value = Range("B1").Value
    Cells(6, 7 + 2 * z).Value = Range("B2").Value
    Cells(7, 7 + 2 * z).Value = Range("B3").Value
    Cells(8, 7 + 2 * z).Value = Range("B4").Value
    Cells(9, 7 + 2 * z).Value = Range("B5").Value
    Cells(10, 7 + 2 * z).Value = Range("B6").Value
    Cells(11, 7 + 2 * z).Value = "Test Name"
    Cells(12, 7 + 2 * z).Value = "Review Cycle Nr."
End Sub
```